# Multiple selction in Dropdownlist of asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Can we select multiple items from razor dropdownlist control. i.e for

**@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Country, CountryList as SelectList,"--Select--")**

Comment: I think you should use '@Html.ListBoxFor` for this

Comment: Why not have a select list that looks like a drop down list? - http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try maybe something like this ...

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.Country, new MultiSelectList(CountryList as SelectList, "CountryID", "Select"))
```

Answer (score 8):

You just have to add a `new { "multiple" = "multiple" }` as last Parameter of the function - this will render a multiselect.

Comment: But how i will get the all selected values after submiting

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved the problem of multiple selection but how i can retrieve all selected values in controller

Comment: This does create a multiple select box, but doesn't allow you to persist the selected options on POST. If the controller is returning a model error, then the user will lose their selected options.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of Items (in this example with fields Id and Name), you can start with a List of SelectListItem as follows:

```
List<SelectListItem> Choices = Items.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = Convert.ToString(x.Id).Trim(), Text = x.Name }).ToList();

@Html.ListBox("ListBoxIds", new MultiSelectList(Choices, "Value", "Text"))
```

In the controller, you will get ListBoxIds as a list of selected Ids.